How to install "iou3d_nms_cuda.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" as a ROS2 module?
I have successfully trained and tested a pointpillars network on my own point cloud dataset using https://github.com/shangjie-li/pointpillars/tree/master. I modified demo_in_ros.py from that repository to apply the trained model for 3D object detection using ROS2 (Humble). I modified setup.py and deom_in_ros.py based on suggestions from this link https://answers.ros.org/question/367793/including-a-python-module-in-a-ros2-package/. I used colcon build and successfully installed all python codes (located in different folders) as modules in ROS2 workspace (ros2_pointpillars) /ros2_pointpillars/install/lidar_object_detection/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lidar_object_detection. I need to use iou3d_nms_cuda.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so which is located in /ops/iou3d_nms folder. How can I install it as a module in ROS2?
I appreciate any help in advance.
#setup.py
from setuptools import setup
package_name = 'lidar_object_detection'
submodules = ['lidar_object_detection.utils',
               'lidar_object_detection.layers.vfe','lidar_object_detection.layers.map_to_bev','lidar_object_detection.layers.backbones_2d','lidar_object_detection.layers.dense_heads',
               'lidar_object_detection.ops.iou3d_nms', 'lidar_object_detection.ops.roiaware_pool3d', 'lidar_object_detection.ops.iou3d_nms.src',
               #'lidar_object_detection.ops.iou3d_nms_cuda',              
               'lidar_object_detection.data', 'lidar_object_detection.data.processor', 'lidar_object_detection.data.kitti_object_eval_python',
               'lidar_object_detection.data.kitti', 'lidar_object_detection.data.augmentor'
               ]


setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name] + submodules,
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='usr',
    maintainer_email='usr@gmail.com',
    description='Object detection',
    license='Apache License 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
               'subscriber = lidar_object_detection.demo_in_ros:main',
        ],
    },
)

#demo_in_ros.py
import argparse
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import time
import os
import sys
import math
import threading
import rclpy
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker, MarkerArray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch

from .ops.iou3d_nms import iou3d_nms_cuda
from .ops.iou3d_nms import iou3d_nms_utils
from .data import cfg, cfg_from_yaml_file
from .data import KittiDataset
from .pointpillar import build_network, load_data_to_gpu
from .utils import common_utils, calibration_kitti
from .utils import opencv_vis_utils
from .utils import numpy_pc2

#package.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>lidar_object_detection</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Object detection</description>
  <maintainer email="usr@gmail.com">usr</maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>
  
  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>visualization_msgs</exec_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

